# How do I name a repository

Tags: apt, updates, ppa, repository

I installed most software from the terminal. I saw that with some programs people give commands like this for example:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:jfi/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install psensor
```

But some just give commands like this:

```
sudo apt-get install psensor
```

If that is the case, and I want to add repository (so that program receives updates more quickly, if I understood it right), how do I know what comes after `ppa:`? How can I find that out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Launchpad:

> Personal Package Archives (PPA) allow users to upload Ubuntu source
>   packages to be built and published as an apt repository by Launchpad

[Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas) is a website developed and maintained by creators of Ubuntu that allows users to develop and maintain open-source software.

If you have found a nice PPA and you want to add it to your repository, this is the general format:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:user/ppa-name
```

Every PPA has its own page in Lanuchpad website. For example, the one mentioned in your post has its page here: https://launchpad.net/~jfi/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

If you look at the PPA's *overview* page, under the heading *Adding this PPA to your system*, you can see the location of PPA. See the below image:

[image]

You can use the location to replace `ppa:user/ppa-name` in the above command. So, in your case it is:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jfi/ppa
```

Comment: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14089/please-can-people-format-code-properly

Answer (score 0):

To know more about PPA's you can read them in [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

If you want to find out the PPA of a repository, you can find them in [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu)